# How to work with a buffer without keeping it in memory

Tags: c, buffer, fifo

I need to play with a buffer FIFO (first in first out) of 3000 elements.

First of all, i will fill this buffer until it is full. After that, when a new element comes, it will replace the oldest element of the buffer. All I want is to compute the sum of the buffer every time a new element comes.

Does anyone know how to do this task without keeping the buffer in the memory?

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like when it's full, and a new element arrives, you need to update the sum by adding the value of the new element and subtracting the value of the oldest element (which is being replaced).  If so, then I think you need to keep all of the elements in the queue.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank for your answer. That's what I'm thinking. But I post this question, maybe someone have the solution

Comment: you can save all elements or all the corresponding sums, but you have to save, else no way to manage the replacement

Comment: What is the element type? If it is an integer type, and you have available a wider integer type that can hold the greatest possible sum without overflow, then it is easy to maintain a running sum. If it is a floating-point type, the maintaining a running sum without accumulating errors may be difficult.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : there are just 0-1 elements. Could you please explain more about your idea? How to update running sum when a new element arrives? Thank you

Comment: Your question is vague and does not show any attempt at solving the problem. Try writing something down yourself, and come back when and if you get stuck. Also, make sure to post a [mre] and explain the details of your FIFO buffer in the post (element type, values, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Associate an additional piece of data, called `sum` with the buffer. Make the type of `sum` large enough to contain the maximum possible sum of the elements in the buffer. When the buffer it initialized to its empty state, set `sum` to zero. When adding a new element `x` to the buffer:

- If the buffer is not full, add `x` to `sum`.
- If the buffer is full, subtract from `sum` the element `y` that is being removed from the buffer, then add `x` to `sum`.

Then `sum` will always contain the sum of the elements currently in the buffer.

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to keep all the buffer in the memory or keep a small part  of it. According to your ideas, I think I must keep all the buffer. Thank you